# If statement filtering with a * character inside the value

Tags: python

I'm iterating a dataframe with the following code:

```
print(access_df)

Out:
                        ActionAccess        Arn
0                               s3:*        a--...
1                       xray:PutTele        b--...
2               s3:*MultipartUpload*        c--...
3            xray:GetSamplingTargets        d--...

for index, row in access_df.iterrows():
    if 's3:*' in row['ActionAccess']:
        print(row)
```

I'm trying to get values that are only `s3:*`. However the above code also detects cases such as `s3:*Object` and `s3:*MultipartUpload*`.

How do I define the if statement to only get values that contain only `s3:*`?

Comment: What do you want to do with 's3:*' ?

Comment: "How do I define the if statement to only get values that are "s3:*"?" Have you tried `==` instead of `in`?

Comment: we should know the type of `row['ActionAccess']` to answer. Apparently it redefines the `in` (via https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

Comment: @walter based on the output shown, aren't they just strings, in which case equality check would be appropriate here rather than the substring check

Comment: I think the question's a bit unclear in that case, maybe I'm not reading it right. I think it needs a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The type is object. The == do the trick.

Comment: I'll add an example of the df so the post has a reproducible example.

Comment: sorry @costaparas, you were right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I really understand the question, but if you just want to check whether the string is *literally* `'s3:*'`, i.e. the `*` is not supposed to be some kind of placeholder/wildcard, just use `==`:

```
if 's3:*' == row['ActionAccess']:
```

If you are looking for `'s3:*'` (but not `'s3:*stuff*'`) as part of a larger string, e.g. `"some string with s3:* inside"`, then you might use `str.split` or resort to a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in regex module [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Then your code could look something like the following.

```
import re
# import other libraries like pandas that you use

for index, row in access_df.iterrows():
    if bool(re.match(r'(s3:\*)',row['ActionAcess'])):
        print(row)
```

This will match a string with s3:*. Bool is used so that you get a boolean to use in your if statement.

You can play around with regex statements on [regexr](https://regexr.com/) to see how it will operate.

**Edit**: re.match matches from the beginning of the string, not anywhere within it.

Comment: This keeps the same problem... `s3:*bla` will also match... Maybe `r's3:\*$` will do but then it's just an overkill of `==`...

Comment: By the way it will not match *anywhere*. `re.match` only matches ***from the start*** of the string. If you want to match anywhere, use `re.search`

Comment: I think equality is whats needed here - not a regex.